# Join que mostre vários dados de um só id

Tags: sql

Eu tenho 3 tabelas: "Terceiros", "Morada_Terceiro", "Contactos_Terceiro". 
O objetivo era: seria inserido um terceiro, o mesmo seria listado, fosse-lhe atribuído uma morada e um contacto, no entanto gostaria que fosse possível atribuir várias moradas a um só terceiro. Utilizei primeiro o INNER JOIN nas 3 tabelas e não foi possível, passei para o LEFT JOIN e quando era introduzido mais que uma morada ou contacto a um terceiro era listado a mesma informação mais que uma vez, acabei por utilizar o RIGHT JOIN e o FULL JOIN e nada. `

```html
//Tabela Terceiros 


 $sql="SELECT Terceiros.*, Email, Telefone, Telemovel, TipoC, Morada, Localidade, CodPostal FROM ((Terceiros INNER JOIN  Contactos_Terceiro on  Terceiros.Numero = Contactos_Terceiro.Numero ) INNER JOIN Morada_Terceiro on Terceiros.Numero = Morada_Terceiro.Numero )";
 if(isset($pesq))
  $sql.=" where Nome like '$pesq' ";
     $sql.=" limit $ini, $tp";
     $res=$lig->query($sql);
```

```html
  
 //Tabela Contactos_Terceiro
  
  $sql="SELECT  Contactos_Terceiro.*, Nome FROM  Contactos_Terceiro INNER JOIN Terceiros on (Terceiros.Numero =  Contactos_Terceiro.Numero)";
 if(isset($pesq))
 $sql.=" where Nome like '$pesq'";
 $sql.=" limit $ini, $tp";
 $res=$lig->query($sql);
```

```html
 //Tabela Morada_Terceiro
  
  $sql="SELECT Morada_Terceiro.*, Nome FROM Morada_Terceiro INNER JOIN Terceiros on (Terceiros.Numero = Morada_Terceiro.Numero)";
 if(isset($pesq))
  $sql.=" where Nome like '$pesq'";
 $sql.=" limit $ini, $tp";
 $res=$lig->query($sql);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]`

Answer (score 0):

Ao utilizar o `inner`, as linhas da tabela **Terceiros** vão se repetir pra cada ocorrência que houver nas outras tabelas.

## Exemplo:

Se fizer um `inner join` da **Terceiros* com **Morada_Terceiro**, se houverem dois registros do mesmo Terceiro na Morada_Terceiro, a query retornará duas linhas: em ambas as linhas os dados da Terceiros será do mesmo registro.

---

Uma alternativa é nesta página fazer a query APENAS na tabela **Terceiros**, e fazer a query nas demais tabelas no momento em que o botão "olho" é clicado.

Comment: O problema é que eu preciso da query nas restantes tabelas porque vou buscar o campo nome da tabela "Terceiros"

Comment: Mas nas outras você pode usar o `join` sem se preocupar com duplicar registros.

Comment: Então faria como? Deixaria como está na tabela Terceiros e as outras 2?

Comment: Nesta página de Listar Terceiros deixaria o `select` apenas da tabela Terceiros; Daí quando clicar no botão, passa o `IdTerceiro` como parâmetro e faz uma segunda query buscando os dados que você precisa referente a este `IdTerceiro`

Comment: **<?php    
$sql= "SELECT Terceiros.*, Email, Telefone, Telemovel, TipoC, Morada, Localidade, CodPostal from Terceiros, Contactos_Terceiro, Morada_Terceiro ";
$sql.="WHERE Contactos_Terceiro.CodCon = Terceiros.CodCon and Morada_Terceiro.Numero = Terceiros.Numero  ";
$res=$lig->query($sql);          
while ($lin=$res->fetch_array()){ ?>**  tentei fazer assim para o botão, mas dá erro

Comment: Que erro? E precisa passar o Id do item selecionado.